# Understanding Infinispan Eviction, Expiration and File store?

Tags: infinispan

Consider a Infinispan cache ( version 5.3.0.Final) Which having following properties,

1. Have file store
2. Passivation is set to true.

I have following problems when understanding the cache behavior.

1. Is there two threads for eviction and expiration ?
2. When expiration thread runs, what happens to entries which are in     file, but has expired ? Do those load back to memory and removed ?
3. What is time duration for these threads to run ?
4. Does the file store file is append-only file ?
5. Does file has a index in this Infinispan version ?
6. What exactly stored in file in this Infinispan version ? Is it key-value or just value ?

Answer (score 3):

I won't speak about such an old version, but it's likely the same.

1. The naming is a bit messy, TBH. There's threadpool with id org.infinispan.executors.eviction with single thread by default, which hosts ScheduledTask that processes *expiration*. Eviction is triggered only when you add something to the data container, and it is processed by the thread that added the new item.
2. Depends on cache store implementation - cachestore SPI has method purgeExpired() which forces removal of expired entries from the store. Nothing needs to be loaded into memory.
3. By default it's 1 minute. Search for wakeUpInterval (or wake-up-interval) in configuration.
4. No, none of the classical file stores. SoftIndexFileStore uses similar technique.
5. FileCacheStore has just several 'buckets' and is based on key hashCode, SingleFileCacheStore (or KarstenFileCacheStore, depends on your version) has in-memory index.
6. Both keys and values.

Comment: The idea behind the naming was to separate expiration (when the entry is removed from the application's point of view) from eviction (when the entry is physically removed from the cache's data container or cache store). Passivation complicated things a bit, because an entry can be evicted from the data container and into the cache store (if the data container is full). But expiration stays the same, and expired entries are unavailable regardless of where they were stored.

Comment: So the confusion comes from overloading the term 'eviction', where it is 'number-of-entities-based removal' in the narrow sense and removal from cache store/data container in the broader one, which includes expiration.