# Eviction for "memory" type is different from "count" type

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, evict

I would like to use Infinispan as cache for image binary data (Java type `byte[]`). I assume that Infinispan default strategy is LIFO or similar strategy that prefers to keep most recently used/added cache entity.

In my loadtest scenario I make four calls in the round to retrieve the given entity. It is assumed that first call never hits the cache (because each round a unique entity is requested), but following three always hit the cache. So the expected profile looks like this:

```
#1: MISS-HIT-HIT-HIT
#2: MISS-HIT-HIT-HIT
...
```

It works perfectly when I configure Infinispan with `COUNT` eviction type with some number of entities:

```
<local-cache name="imagesCache" statistics="true">
    <!-- lifespan="30 min" max-idle="30 min" interval="1 min" -->
    <expiration lifespan="1800000" max-idle="1800000" interval="60000" />
    <memory>
        <binary eviction="COUNT" size="500" />
    </memory>
</local-cache>
```

The stats shows exact 3/4 cache hit at the end of the run (as well as in the middle):
[image: Cache JMX stats for COUNT type in the middle]

Cache hit ratio based on numbers I capture in loadtest: `(2952-738)/2952 = 0.75`

When I change the number of entities to keep in the memory (`<binary eviction="COUNT" size="100" />`), hit ratio does not change (*as expected*).

During the run I have measured heap size before and after load test (measurements taken after several GC invocations) and it turns out that 500 entities take about `114.895.000 - 62.445.000 = 52.450.000` bytes = roughly 100KB per entity:
[image: Cache heap stats for COUNT type at the end]

After that I have restarted the application with only this small change in cache configuration:

```
<memory>
    <binary eviction="MEMORY" size="1000000" />
</memory>
```

I would expect that Infinispan performance has the same profile, however it turns out that once the given amount of memory is fully allocated, newly added entities don't evict old entities but get immediately evicted. It means that roughly after 100 entities are added, all four requests to cache result cache miss. One can see that ratio is now 0.58 instead of 0.75:
[image: Cache heap stats for MEMORY type at the end]

Cache hit ratio: `(2952-738-504)/2952 = 0.579`

If I increase the memory, indeed hit ratio comes closer to 0.75 however I would like hit ratio to be the same irrespective the memory size (provided that memory can fit at least few entities).

Once I configure the passivation to file, memory-based eviction policy starts to work as expected:

```
<local-cache name="imagesCache" statistics="true">
    <expiration lifespan="1800000" max-idle="1800000" interval="60000" />
    <persistence passivation="true">
        <file-store path="/var/cache/infinispan" purge="true">
            <write-behind thread-pool-size="5" />
        </file-store>
    </persistence>
    <memory>
        <binary eviction="MEMORY" size="1000000" />
    </memory>
</local-cache>
```

[image]

*Passivation → Attributes* shows that number of passivations is 1121 (equal to number of evictions) and *Activation → Attributes* shows that number of activations is 1242. It means that some entities have been activated several times (and immediately evicted, which is not good). In general I expect that number of activations is zero.

Any idea how to configure memory-based eviction policy so that cache hit ratio is the same as for count-based policy?

Topics I've read in relation to above (they don't have a direct answer to above question):

- [Understanding Infinispan Eviction, Expiration and File store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983060/)
- [Infinispan size eviction + diskStore overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304501/)
- [Infinispan data eviction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185830/)

Comment: The eviction method used for OBJECT and BINARY storage types are handled by caffeine. I wonder if you are running into something like [1].

Can you try with OFFHEAP instead of BINARY to see what the difference is?

[1] https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/pull/4578#discussion_r89361174

Comment: Caffeine will try to evict recent, low frequency items rather than pollute the cache. This usually works [very well](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency), but does take a little warm-up. Recent work has gone towards being adaptive to dynamically tune for frequency or recency based on the workload. If you'd like to run your test against Caffeine, we can investigate the trace and understand the policy's decision process. If so, we can move this to email or the issue tracker.

Comment: @Mudokonman: Thanks for the explanation. Indeed what is highlighted in the post you've linked takes place in my experiment: the newly added entity becomes immediately the candidate for eviction. Even tough the number of activations is too high (should be not more than 1121): once activated, the entity should get higher frequency score.

Comment: @BenManes: I will appreciate if the issue is registered in bugtracker for further investigation. If you prefer I can file it myself.

Comment: @dma_k, I think you should do it, because you have all test code necessary to reproducing it.

Comment: @Mudokonman: I have changed the configuration to `<off-heap eviction="MEMORY" size="10000000" />` and cache works as expected (hit ratio 0.75). It looks like an acceptable workaround...

Comment: @dma_k Great, yeah it sounds like the issue needs to move to caffeine bug tracker which can be found at [1].

Also if you wanted to I can help with tweaking your config if you wanted to post at [2].

[1] https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues
[2] https://developer.jboss.org/en/infinispan

Comment: Filed as [ISPN-9023](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-9023). I hope that bugs are actually reviewed by the team, as [ISPN-8691](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-8691) which I've submitted months ago is still in status "New".

Comment: @dma_k The bugs get reviewed, but [there'll be no progress unless you provide more information](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/229#issuecomment-379108606).